# How to Dynamically Map Subdirectory Requests to DocumentRoot in Apache

Tags: apache, configuration

I'd like to dynamically map requests to different api versions in the following manner.

- http://example.com/v1.1 should map to /var/www/vhosts/api/versions/v1.1/public/
- http://example.com/v1.2 should map to /var/www/vhosts/api/versions/v1.2/public/
- http://example.com/v1.3 should map to /var/www/vhosts/api/versions/v1.3/public/
- ...
- http://example.com/v1.n should map to /var/www/vhosts/api/versions/v1.n/public/

How can I accomplish this in Apache without modifying the example.com.conf file every time a new api version is published?

At first I thought that VirtualDirectoryRoot might be promising, but that appears to only operate on the domain segments rather than URI segments.

Note: I'm using Apache 2.4.7

Answer (score 0):

```
AliasMatch /(v\d+\.\d+)/ /var/www/vhosts/api/versions/$1/
<Directory  /var/www/vhosts/api/versions/*>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I didn't have any luck with variations of this approach.  That might be because of some other configuration though.  Thank you for trying.